# C programming, while loop

Tags: c

I was reading code and came across a while loop structured like this:

```
while(q--)
```

I understand that this is a post decrement operator, but I don't understand the condition that is being tested in the while loop

thanks for your time, Connor

Answer (score 6):

A `while` loop checks if the condition is true.

An expression that evaluates to 0 is considered false, while any non-zero expression is considered true.

From section 6.8.5 of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *4* An iteration statement causes a statement called the loop body to be executed repeatedly **until the controlling expression compares equal
>   to 0**.  The repetition occurs regardless of whether the loop body is
>   entered from the iteration statement or by a jump

So this loop tests if `q` is non-zero.  Once `q` is decremented to 0, the loop exits.

Comment: @ConnorShorten Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

IN C a "TRUE" is represented by NON-Zero-Value. So the loop will run until "q" reaches "0".

This is lazy-bad programming. It does not take that much effort to make the code clear and precise.

while( (q--)!=0) Would be more appropriate.
or
    while (q!=0)
      {
       q--;
    //.......
      }

Comment: This is also idiomatic C, preferred by some for its concision. It is certainly important to be able to understand common idioms. But I would not say that this construction is necessarily lazy or bad.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the expression `while(q--)` is equal to

```
while(q == true)
{
    q--;
}
```

since `while` compares what's in between the parantheses to `true` and at the same time can do operations, same as `for loop`.
Note that the value 1 means `true` and the value 0 means `false` so as soon as you have `q= 0` the condition will return `false` which will make the loop stop.